# Errors while installing Qtbindings on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, qt, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install Qtbindings (for Ruby) on Ubuntu, but each try I have the same errors... I don't understand why. Here the result :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/louis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/libruby-static.a(array.o): réadressage R_X86_64_PC32 vers symbole « rb_ary_entry » ne peut pas être utilisé en créant un objet partagé ; recompilé avec -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: édition de lien finale en échec: Mauvaise valeur
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry it's in french, I hope you'll understand  ! The complete log is [here](https://gist.github.com/boopr/e142fd48054194898af6). (too long to be posted here).

I follow the instruction of the [Qtbindings' github](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings), I installed

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5
  libreadline-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev vim
  libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3
  libxml2-dev git-core subversion autoconf xorg-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
  libglu1-mesa-dev
```

But I still have the error... My Ruby version is the 2.2.1p85.

I hope you have an answer for me !
Thank's for your help !

Comment: as said on the error, add the -fPIC in the CFLAGS and recompile it

Comment: But I can't add this flags on a gem instruction... `gem install qtbindings`

Comment: sorry, I was unclear; you have to recompile ruby  with -fPIC (`/home/louis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/libruby-static.a` is the wrong file)